# How to fix .index() method returning the wrong value?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to get the index of the values higher than 70 from the following list:

```
temperatures = [33, 66, 65, 62, 59, 60, 62, 64, 70, 76, 80, 69, 80, 83, 68, 79, 61, 53, 50, 49, 53, 48, 45, 39]
```

But something is going wrong when the loop finds equal values:

```
hour_ex = []
for i in temperatures:
    if i > 70:
        hour_ex.append(temperatures.index(i))

print(hour_ex)
```

The code above is printing:

```
[9, 10, 10, 13, 15]
```

When the loop reach the index 12, it prints again the index 10 because it has the same value. I don't know what's going on. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`index` is a list-searching function that performs a linear walk through the list to find the first position of a given element. This explains your confusing output--in the case of duplicates like 80, `index()` will always give you the first index it can find for that element, which is 10.

Use `enumerate()` if you're interested in obtaining the indices as a tuple for each element of the list.

Additionally, the variable `i` suggests index, but actually represents a given temperature in the list; it's a misleading variable name.

```
temperatures = [33, 66, 65, 62, 59, 60, 62, 64, 70, 76, 80, 69, 80, 83, 68, 79, 61, 53, 50, 49, 53, 48, 45, 39]    
hour_ex = []

for i, temperature in enumerate(temperatures):
    if temperature > 70:
        hour_ex.append(i)

print(hour_ex) # => [9, 10, 12, 13, 15]
```

Consider using a list comprehension, which performs a filtering operation on the enumerated list:

```
hour_ex = [i for i, temp in enumerate(temperatures) if temp > 70]
```

Comment: OP is asking for a list of indices, not of values.

Comment: Thanks ggorlen. Now I got properly the .index() behavior and why use enumerate. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

From the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html) for `list.index(x[, start[, end]])`:

> Return zero-based index in the list of the **first** item whose value is equal to x. Raises a ValueError if there is no such item.

To achieve what you are trying to do, you could do the following:

```py
hour_ex = [i for i, n in enumerate(temperatures) if n > 70]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use range in the loop:

```
temperatures = [33, 66, 65, 62, 59, 60, 62, 64, 70, 76, 80, 69, 80, 83, 68, 79, 61, 53, 50, 49, 53, 48, 45, 39]

hour_ex = []
for i in range(len(temperatures)):
    if temperatures[i] > 70:
        hour_ex.append(i)

print(hour_ex)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In simple terms, index() method finds the given element in a list and returns its position.

However, if the same element is present more than once, index() method returns its smallest/first position.
```

So, if has duplicate value in list `index` will return smallest index of value

You can try

```py
hour_ex = []
for idx, temper in enumerate(temperatures):
    if temper > 70:
        hour_ex.append(idx)

print(hour_ex)
```